# Creating a Webserive job in Control-M with JWT Authentication

Tags: control-m

I need to create a control-m job of Webservice type. In this job I need to call a POST API which is authenticated using a JWT token. The token has to be generated from the control-m
using a client secret and token and sent in the request headers.

Is there any way I can achieve this in control-m job?